# Cancel row edit p:datatable does not revert data for dependant selectonemenus

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, selectonemenu

I have an issue with dependant selectonemenus in Primefaces datatables for which I haven't found an answer.  I assume others have had the same issue so there must be a solution for it.  What's going on is that when I edit a row in a data table then cancel the edit, whatever change I made to the first selectonemenu remains in the backing object and does not revert to its original value. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Open a row for editing
2. change a value in the first column (you can verify that the second column list has changed.
3. cancel the row edit
4. The first column value does not revert to original

I think it has something to do with the ajax call to the backing bean's listener.  It's like the value is getting posted.  This is not desirable behavior.  Is there a fix for this?

I am including code samples below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

<f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:head>  
    <title>
        <ui:insert name="title">Example One</ui:insert>
    </title>
</h:head>  

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:messages/>
        <p:dataTable id="editTable" var="item" value="#{exampleOne.items}" editable="true" scrollable="false" scrollHeight="350" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{exampleOne.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{exampleOne.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />
            <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{exampleOne.onRowInit}" />

            <p:column headerText="Name" style="width: 100px;">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="tagId" value="#{item.name}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Column One" style="width: 200px;">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.columnOneValue}"/></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="columnOneId" value="#{item.columnOneValue}" style="width:100%">
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{exampleOne.onColumnOneChange}" update="columnTwoId" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Column One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{exampleOne.columnOneSelectItems}" var="columnOneSelectItem" itemLabel="#{columnOneSelectItem}" itemValue="#{columnOneSelectItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Column Two" style="width: 125px;">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.columnTwoValue}"/></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="columnTwoId" value="#{item.columnTwoValue}" style="width:100%">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Column Two" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{exampleOne.columnTwoSelectItems}" var="columnTwoSelectItem" itemLabel="#{columnTwoSelectItem}" itemValue="#{columnTwoSelectItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width: 75px;">
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>


        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>  

package com.windhaven_consulting.breezy.controller.ui;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIOutput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import com.windhaven_consulting.breezy.component.MountedBoard;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ExampleOne implements Serializable {

private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

private List<String> columnOneSelectItems = new ArrayList<String>();

private Map<String, List<String>> columnOneToColumnTwoMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

private List<String> columnTwoSelectItems;

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    items.add(new Item("item 1", "Select One", "Select One A"));
    items.add(new Item("item 2", "Select Two", "Select Two A"));
    items.add(new Item("item 3", "Select Three", "Select Three A"));

    columnOneSelectItems.add("Select One");
    columnOneSelectItems.add("Select Two");
    columnOneSelectItems.add("Select Three");

    List<String> columnTwoSelectItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select One One");
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select One Two");
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select One Three");
    columnOneToColumnTwoMap.put("Select One", columnTwoSelectItems);

    columnTwoSelectItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select Two One");
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select Two Two");
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select Two Three");
    columnOneToColumnTwoMap.put("Select Two", columnTwoSelectItems);

    columnTwoSelectItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select Three One");
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select Three Two");
    columnTwoSelectItems.add("Select Three Three");
    columnOneToColumnTwoMap.put("Select Three", columnTwoSelectItems);
}

public void onRowInit(RowEditEvent event) {
}

public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
}

public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
}

public void onColumnOneChange(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    String selectedValue = (String) ((UIOutput) event.getSource()).getValue();

    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(selectedValue)) {
        columnTwoSelectItems = columnOneToColumnTwoMap.get(selectedValue);
    }
    else {
        columnTwoSelectItems = Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public List<String> getColumnOneSelectItems() {
    return columnOneSelectItems;
}

public List<String> getColumnTwoSelectItems() {
    return columnTwoSelectItems;
}
}
```

Comment: Try adding `process='@this'` to the ajax handler. And next time, please make the example code even more minimal…  [mcve]

Comment: Just tried it and there is no change in behavior.  Btw, are there any really good resources out there with detailed examples?  This is common functionality that I'm sure has already been solved long ago.

Comment: cellEditor and rowEditor are not the most common ones in usage. I never use it. Always update/edit data in a dialog or even a full new page.To much hassle with this this functionality. Tried using `process="@none"`?

Comment: I appreciate your help.  This is disappointing as it would make user experience easier.  I will opt for a dialog just to get this completed.  Cheers

Comment: That doesn't work either.  My second selectonemenu doesn't get updated.  Dialogue it is!